# How can I set the states (names) after using markovchainFit for plotting?

Tags: r, plot, markov-chains, google-colaboratory, markov

here is my contrived dataset/logic to plot markovchain

```
sequences <- list(
      c("Opened", "2709342", "END"),
      c("Opened", "3067630", "END")
    )

    sequencesMarkovchainFit <- function(sequences){
      # Create a continuous sequence string with each sequence having START and END
      #
      # sequences <- list( c("A"),
      #                    c("B"))
      # sequence = c("START", "A", "END", "START", "B", "END" ...)
      sequence <- c ()
      for (i in 1:length(sequences)){
        #sequence <- c(sequence, "START", unlist(sequences[i]), "END")
        sequence <- c(sequence, "START", unlist(sequences[i]))
      }
      fit <- markovchainFit(data=sequence)
      chain <- as(fit$estimate, "markovchain")
      return(chain)
    }

    sequencesMC <- sequencesMarkovchainFit(sequences)

    plot(sequencesMC, main="Selected Sequences T (transition matrix)")
```

and the resulting plot still has the indices (i.e. 0,1,2..) instead of the desired states (names)

[plot of markovchain after creating with markovchainFit](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otBHf.png)

Comment: I've tagged this question `r` because in my experience questions with `<-` in the code and no mention of the programming language used tend to be R related. If I'm wrong, please remove it :-)

Comment: oh sorry, thanks. Yes it's R code.

Comment: When I run your code,  I get the labels "START", "Opened", "2709342", "3067630", "END"   Not the numbers that you show.

Comment: my apologies...in Rstudio, yes this works.

I am actually deploying this in Google's colab